# Expressing 1-e^{-z} as a Fourier integral

Tags: fourier-analysis, integration, fourier-transform, laplace-transform

According to the theory of screw functions and screw lines by John Von Neumann and Issai Schoenberg (see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1989957.pdf?casa_token=-RNg9od01gsAAAAA:Pm5cdJk4ue0_JGYoYBZkZEmPgt-b8Ahoz6Ec0MVMcymKHQWFewOPy_zDvefMpo4cVhy9tEHEbcHsCvtVtMSgq3omDZDo29weHUUpfVWn8S4-GL4bpXwA)), any function $F:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(|x_i - x_j|) = \|f(x_i)-f(x_j)\|_2^2$ for some function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow H$ (for some Hilbert space $H$) can be written as:

$F(t) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(tx)}{x^2} d\gamma (x)$

where
$\int_1^\infty x^{-2} \gamma'(x) dx$ is finite.

Experimentally, I've determined that the function $F(t) = 1-e^{-|t|}$ has the property that $F(|x_i-x_j|)$ can be written as $\|f(x_i)-f(x_j)\|_2^2$. How would I go about finding $\gamma$ for this function (or any such function $F$?).

Comment: $e^{-|t|} = C\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(2tx)}{4x^2+1}dx$

Comment: How did you come up with this? Apologies if this is all common konwledge. (Also, how would you come up with such a formula given some arbitrary function F?)

Comment: @TimothyChu, you want #207 from [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms).

Comment: By (inverse) Fourier transform?

Comment: Ah, great. Thanks! I feel silly for asking such a basic question :).